How do I set metadata for an AVIF (AV1) file
I'm trying to set metadata for an avif file (new image format) but it is not working by using the command that I would expect to use:
ffmpeg -ss 60 -i "input.mkv" -metadata title="test" -metadata comment="test2" -frames:v 1 -c:v libaom-av1 "output.avif"

When I access the properties of the files in Windows I don't see nothing. When I use ffprobe I get this for the metadata:

Link: Output.avif

Windows appears to read/write standard EXIF data in AVIF using Windows 11.
ffmpeg doesn't write EXIF data, so another program such as exiftool would have to be used.
The tags that Windows read to fill the various properties under the Details tab can be found in this exiftool forum post.
In order to set the "Title" and "Comment" properties, you could try this exiftool command
exiftool -ImageDescription="Title" -UserComment="Comment" /path/to/files/

This command creates backup files.  Add -overwrite_original to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add -r to recurse into subdirectories.

If Windows doesn't read metadata for avif why can I manually modify some fields like: Copyright, date taken, Camera Manufacturer, Camera Model, Lens Manufacturer throught the file properties \ Details window and when I close the property Window and open again they are still there?

What version of Windows are you using? I'm on Win10, and I'm unable to edit any of these. Can you make a copy of such a file available, so I can look at it in detail?

I'm on Windows 11. I added a link to the file in my question, thanks for your time.

Win10 doesn't show any details. But looking at the file with exiftool, I should have guessed that Windows would be writing standard image metadata. You'll have to use a program such as exiftool. The tags you will want to write are XMP:Title, XMP:Description, IPTC:Caption-Abstract, EXIF:ImageDescription, and/or EXIF:XPTitle, though I would discourage writing the last one as that is a Windows only tag. This post on the exiftool forums will show what tags you would write for other windows properties.

Never mind about the IPTC:Caption-Abstract tag, AVIF do not support IPTC IIM metadata. I'm curious if Windows would read XMP data in this file. EXIF:ImageDescription is probably your best choice, as Windows only wrote EXIF data and not XMP data as it normally would for Copyright.

Whatever I try to change with exiftool doesn't show up on Windows file property page only on exiftool. Am I using this right: exiftool -exif:Imagedescription output.avif ?

That command will only read the ImageDescription. I edited my answer to give an example command to add "Title" and "Comment".  Try that to see if it works. If it doesn't, then I would say that Windows doesn't read that specific tag in AVIF files. Something similar happens with Windows and PNG files, it only reads one tag and nothing else.

thank you for trying but no luck.

Can you share a sample image that Windows shows with the data you entered in your first comment? It will need to be through something like Dropbox or Google drive to preserve the data.
